# React Native Error : The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K

Tags: android, npm, react-native

After executing:  npx react-native run-android , it is giving following error...

.
.
.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
> Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Here are my dependencies :
"dependencies": {

- "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
- "@react-native-firebase/app": "^10.5.0",
- "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.4",
- "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.0",
- "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.1",
- "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.0",
- "axios": "^0.21.1",
- "native-base": "^2.15.2",
- "react": "16.13.1",
- "react-native": "0.63.4",
- "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
- "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
- "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.3",
- "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
- "react-native-paper": "^4.7.0",
- "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
- "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
- "react-native-screens": "^2.15.2",
- "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0-rc.3",
- "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.0.0",
- "react-native-webview": "^11.2.0",
- "styled-components": "^5.2.1"
  },

Comment: Did you try going to the link it provides to resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes, I did, I follow the steps given there, after that neither any error is showing, nor the app is running. It is only showing a white screen(that is also only for a second). I can't able to find what exactly the error is.